# S1 EP20: How did Mikasa know Armin said Eren might be in the rear of the centre rank of the formation?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In season 1 episode 20, Armin figured out that Eren might be in the rear of the centre rank after the fight with the female titan. After that, he and Mikasa never met up.

However, about 15 minutes into the episode, Mikasa was thinking about something in the forest and recalled that Armin mentioned that Eren would be in the rear centre rank. But that makes no sense given they never met up after Armin figured it out and so Armin could never have told her.

So how could Mikasa know that Armin figured out that Eren was in the rear centre rank?

Comment: Good question. There is no answer to this. I*ve researched the manga, wiki, and rewatched the anime. However, Mikasa would have eventually known where Eren is anyway because she heard his _Titan scream_.

Answer (score -1):

Well most probably because they could have noticed that the flank formation they both received had no location marked for Eren, and Armin could have figured it out before they went for the expedition.

As such, there is no such mention in the manga, so we can only speculate what might have happened.

Comment: Armin could not have figured it out before they went out for the expedition. He figured it out during the expedition.

Comment: Did you listen what Mikasa said? Armin "guessed" that they might be in rear centre.Logically, that would've been the safest position in the entire formation. Remember, in episode 16 where scouting formation was told to Mikasa and Armin, you can hear Armin saying that Eren's position was mentioned nowhere in the scouting report. That's why he would've guessed and told Mikasa where Eren would most likely be.